# Copy data from multiple Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder which have 155 Excel files. I have to copy F row from all 155 Excel files into one common sheet. Can this is possible using macro

Thanks
~ravi

Comment: Please understand that this is no free code writing service. Read [ask] and [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) to improve your question and show what you already have tried.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ FYI I never asked for any code. I was asking for suggestions if this is possible with Excel or not.

Comment: If this is your question then: Yes, this is definitely possible with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean F column?  How about this?

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Filepath As String
Dim count as Integer
Filepath = "D:\DATA\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
count = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

While MyFile <> ""
    If MyFile = "master.xlsm" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    Workbooks(MyFile).sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1:F100").Copy thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, count)
    Workbooks(MyFile).Close
    count = count + 1
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```